# How to make a drop down menu operate correctly?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a drop down menu that pops out to the left but not only does the first inline dropdown pop to the left but the top part isn't align with the appropriate element that has the [drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfCSb.png).

And the rest of the drop down overlaps on top one another. Not only that, but I want the width of the "Moment" the same as the drop down.

The HTML code:

```
                 <nav class="submenu" id="submenu">
                <ul class="submenu">
                <li id="main"><a href="main-index.html" title="Main">Main</a></li>
                <li id="opinions"><a href="opinions.html" title="Opinion Page">Opinions</a></li>
                <li id="characters"><a href="table.html" title="Character Sheet">Characters</a></li>
                <li id="quotes"><a href="dl.html" title="Quotes">Quotes</a></li>
                <li id="moments"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Crowning Moments">Moments</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li id="funny_moment"><a href="funny.html" title="Moments of Funny">Funny</a></li>
                        <li id="tearjerker_moment"><a href="tearjerker.html" title="Moments of Tearjerker">Tearjerker</a></li>
                        <li id="awesome_moment"><a href="heartwarming.html" title="Moments of Heartwarming">Heartwarming</a></li>
                        <li id="heartwarming_moment"><a href="awesome.html" title="Moments of Awesome">Awesome</a></li>
                        <li id=""><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Other Moments">Other</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Fridge">Fridge</a>
                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                        <li id="fridge_logic"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Fridge Logic">Logic</a></li>
                                        <li id="fridge_brilliance"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Fridge Brilliance">Brilliance</a></li>
                                        <li id="fridge_horror"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Fridge Horror">Horror</a></li>
                                        <li id="fridge_heartwarming"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Fridge Heartwarming">Heartwarming</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Fuels">Fuel</a>
                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                        <li id="fuel_nightmare"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Nightmare Fuel">Nightmare</a></li>
                                        <li id="fuel_nausea"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Nausea Fuel">Nausea</a></li>
                                        <li id="fuel_fetishism"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Fetishism Fuel">Fetishism</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Fails">Fail</a>
                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                        <li id="fail_nightmare"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Nightmare Fail">Nightmare</a></li>
                                        <li id="fail_nausea"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Nausea Fail">Nausea</a></li>
                                        <li id="fail_fetishism"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Fetishism Fail">Fetishism</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li id="scene"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Scene">Scene</a></li>
                                <li id="awesome_music"><a href="/" onclick="return false;" title="Awesome Music">Awesome Music</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And the CSS code:

```
/***** div *****/
.menu {
    margin: auto;
}

/***** submenu *****/
#menu {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    list-style-type: none; /*bullet removel*/
    list-style: none; /*bullet removel*/
    text-decoration: none; /*bullet removel*/
    padding-bottom: 1.1em;
}

ul.submenu {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.submenu li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#moments  li {
    width: 241px;
}

ul.submenu li a {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #fdfdfa;
    border: 2px solid #dab175;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7.5px;
    transition: all 0.1s;
}

ul.submenu li:hover > a {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #fdfdfa;
    border: 2px solid #955e33;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7.5px;
}

/***** Drop-Down submenu *****/
ul.submenu li:hover > ul {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}

ul.submenu ul, ul.submenu ul li ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: inherit;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; 
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; 
    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; 
    transition:opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear;     
}

ul.submenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

#moments {
    width: 241px;
}

ul.submenu ul li ul {
   position: absolute;
   left: -240px;
}

ul.submenu ul li a {
    padding:5px 8px;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    width:220px;
}

ul.submenu ul li ul li a {
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

ul.submenu ul li {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    border:0 none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #c9c9c9;
}

ul.submenu ul li ul li a:hover {
    float: right;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to make the Moments item the same size as the dropdown you would probably do somehting like:

```
#moments {
    width: 241px;
}
```

To get rid of overlap you can add a bit of margin to the li elements:

```
ul.submenu li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

And what Tuguldur said for the other part.

Comment: I have fixed the pop-out adjustment but am still having issues with the options elements not being of the same width and the dropdown still appears at the top. I have followed what was said but isn't working. I even updated the question above, including a new picture.

Comment: Add your code to jsfiddle.net and then reply with the link and I'll show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine. But 250px was static.

```
.ul li ul{
   position: absolute;
   left: 250px;
}
```

replace your `.ul li ul {}` styles.